# What assumptions must be made for a metric space $X$ such that all continuous functions $f: X\rightarrow X$ have a fixed point?

Tags: metric-spaces, fixed-points

So basically, I’m looking for a set of constraints on a metric space $X$ such that every continuous function from $ X\rightarrow X$ has a fixed point. Obviously such  metric spaces do exist, with the trivial example being $X = \{x\}$ (equipped with any metric), but I would be surprised if that was the only example.

At first I thought maybe it would be enough for $X$ to be compact and complete, but the unit circle is a counterexample to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The fixed point theorem of Brouwer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem) might be what you're looking for

Conditions: X is compact and convex (in an Hilbert space - it's also true for Banach spaces by [Schauder fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_fixed-point_theorem) )

Answer (score 0):

See this Wikipedia article on the [Fixed Point Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_property) of topological spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The Lefschetz fixed point theorem is a generalization of Brouwer's fixed point theorem. See e.g.

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem mit.edu/~ivogt/LefschetzFixedPointTheorem.pdf

It deals with compact polyhedra $X$ and gives a sufficient criterion in order that each $f : X \to X$ has a fixed point.